# Replace query parameters in Uri.Builder in Android?

Tags: android, uri, uribuilder

I'm passing around a Uri.Builder object as a mechanism for subclasses to fill in whatever parameters necessary into a Uri before it is executed in **Android**.

Problem is, one of the parameters that the base class adds using `builder.appendQueryParameter("q",searchPhrase);` needs to be replaced in the sub-class, but I can only find `appendQueryParameter()`, there is no replace or set method. `appendQueryParameter()` with the same parameter name adds another instance of the parameter, doesn't replace it.

Should I give up and try another way? Or is there a way to replace query parameters that I haven't found yet?

Answer (score 24):

Since there is no in-built method, the best way I have found is to build a new Uri. You iterate over all the query parameters of the old Uri and then replace the desired key with the new value.

```
private static Uri replaceUriParameter(Uri uri, String key, String newValue) {
    final Set<String> params = uri.getQueryParameterNames();
    final Uri.Builder newUri = uri.buildUpon().clearQuery();
    for (String param : params) {
        newUri.appendQueryParameter(param, 
            param.equals(key) ? newValue : uri.getQueryParameter(param));
    }

    return newUri.build();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This will add a parameter, or replace an existing parameter's value in Kotlin.

**Extension of Uri:**

```
fun Uri.addUriParameter(key: String, newValue: String): Uri {
    val params = queryParameterNames
    val newUri = buildUpon().clearQuery()
    var isSameParamPresent = false
    for (param in params) {
        // if same param is present override it, otherwise add the old param back
        newUri.appendQueryParameter(param,
                if (param == key) newValue else getQueryParameter(param))
        if (param == key) {
            // make sure we do not add new param again if already overridden
            isSameParamPresent = true
        }
    }
    if (!isSameParamPresent) {
        // never overrode same param so add new passed value now
        newUri.appendQueryParameter(key,
                newValue)
    }
    return newUri.build()
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
val appendedURL = originalUri.addUriParameter("UID","123456")
```

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat more concise way of doing what @bmjohns is suggesting.

```
fun Uri.addUriParameter(key: String, newValue: String): Uri =
  with(buildUpon()) {
    clearQuery()
    queryParameterNames.forEach {
      if (it != key) appendQueryParameter(it, getQueryParameter(it))
    }
    appendQueryParameter(key, newValue)
    build()
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/*
 * Append or replace query parameters
 */
fun Uri.Builder.addQueryParameters(uri: Uri, params: Map<String, String>) = apply {
    if (uri.query == null) {
        appendQueryParameters(params)
    } else {
        clearQuery()
        appendQueryParameters(params)
        val names = params.keys
        uri.queryParameterNames.forEach {
            if (it !in names) appendQueryParameter(it, uri.getQueryParameter(it))
        }
    }
}

fun Uri.Builder.appendQueryParameters(params: Map<String, String>) = apply {
    params.forEach { name, value ->
        appendQueryParameter(name, value)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem ago, and decide to go another way.

Make an wrapper class and store queries (say `setQueryParameter(key, value)`) in `Map` (or `ArrayMap`, something like that).

Then wrapper instance's `build()` method processes original `Builder`'s `appendQueryParameter()` and `build()`

Comment: Yeah well, I was already maintaining the parameters in a HashMap, but in my query engine I came upon the need for Array parameters for a particular API and the requirement broke my usage of the HashMap. So I converted everything to use the Uri.Builder directly. And then, this replacement requirement came up. I guess I'll have to do both. :(

Answer (score 0):

With `UrlQuerySanitizer` -

```
  val sanitizer = UrlQuerySanitizer(serviceUrl)
  val paramVal = sanitizer.getValue("byCustomValue")
  val replacedUrl = serviceUrl.replace(paramVal, "REPLACE_HERE")
```

Here is a simple method to encode a specific param -

```
  fun encodeParameter(url: String, key: String): String {
        val sanitizer = UrlQuerySanitizer(url)
        return if (sanitizer.hasParameter(key)) {
            val paramValue = sanitizer.getValue(key)
            val encodedValue = try {
                URLEncoder.encode(paramValue, "utf-8")
            } catch (e: UnsupportedEncodingException) {
                paramValue
            }
            url.replace(paramValue, encodedValue)
        } else url
    }
```

Comment: What if inside the url there is another char sequence with the same value as the one you are replacing with?